# setState(...) called on an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

I have recently begun using ReactJs and am trying to dynamically populate a table. My code is as follows :

```
export default class StatsTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            tableData   : [],
        }
    }

populateTable(){
    var tableDataList = [];
    data = this.state.tableData;
    data.map(function (row){
        tableDataList.push(
            <tr key={row.id}>
            <td>{row.id}</td>
        </tr>)
    });
    return tableDataList;
}

handleActions(action){
    switch(action.type){
        case "TABLE_DATA_RECEIVED" :
            var tableInput = action.data.data;
            this.setState({tableData : tableInput});
            break;
    }
}

loadStatsTable() {
    loadTable(); //Triggers an ajax query that emits the message and data received
}

render(){
    return(<div>
            <Button onClick={this.loadStatsTable.bind(this)}>Load</Button>
            <Table>
              <thead>{this.populateTable()}</tbody>
            </Table>
          </div>);
    }
}
```

I however get a warning message : `Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the StatsTable component.`

When I fire the request. 
Why do I get the error? Since, the component has already mounted (page has loaded completely), when I click the button?
What is the fix?

Note : the `populateTable()` function works fine when I try to populate it using a static list. The error occurs when I use `this.setState({tableData : tableInput});`

Comment: And what `loadTable` does? And how `handleActions` is called?

Comment: loadTable initiates an AJAX call action, which emits "TABLE_DATA_RECEIVED". handleActions has been registered to the dispatcher of StatsTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wherever you are registering `handleActions` as callback, you need to undo it in `componentWillUnmount` life cycle hook.

```
componentWillUnmount() {
      //Unregister handleActions from dispatcher
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing this.state.tableData into populate table from within your render.

`<Table>
    <thead>{this.populateTable(this.state.tableData)}</tbody>
</Table>`

Comment: Try going further ```{this.state.tableData.map((item)=>this.buildRow(item)}```